# How to add multiple affiliations in the tikzposter class?

Tags: formatting, affiliation, tikzposter

I've been working through the `tikzposter` class documentation, but so far I couldn't find any hint as to how add affiliation to multiple authors. For example:

Something like this isn't really working:

```
\affiliation{First Institution}{1}
\affiliation{Second Institution}{2}

\author{Firstauthor}{1}
\author{Coauthor}{2}
\author{Othercoauthor}{2}
```

Update: Somehow Gonzalo's solution is outputting this on my machine (OSX with TeXlive)

[image: output]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`authblk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{The Title}
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}

\author[1]{Author A}
\author[2]{Author B}
\author[2]{Author C}
\affil[1]{Department One, University One}
\affil[2]{Department Two, University Two}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

An image showing part of the resulting title:

[image]

#### Update

To prevent some shifting for blocks in `tikzposter`, noticed in the edit to the question, one needs to do

```
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{The Title}
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}
\author[1]{Author A}
\author[2]{Author B}
\author[2]{Author C}
\affil[1]{Department One, University One}
\affil[2]{Department Two, University Two}

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I just realised, that however working, I get the first of my blocks displaced to the middle of the poster when using authblk and a space between title and this first block of about one third of the poster... Are there any known incompatibilities?

Comment: @EnriqueManjavacas Not that I'm aware of. Can you please add to your question a simpe complete document (like the one in my answer) showing the undesired behaviour?

Comment: actually the very same document that you posted produces the undesired output

Comment: @EnriqueManjavacas the exact code I posted or with some modification? You mentioned you added some space?

Comment: I've just updated the output of your answer on my machine

Comment: @EnriqueManjavacas Please see my updated answer for a solution. Don't forget that, if you consider an answer solved your problem, you can marked as accepted by clicking the checkmark to its left; in case of doubts, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: great! now it's working. Would you mind a short explanation for newbies about what's going on in your solution? thanks!

Comment: @emanjavacas Sure! Right now I have to leave, but later I'll add some explanation (basically, the `authblk` package makes a redefinition of `tabular` inside `\maketitle` which my code overrides).

Comment: Nice solution. Please note that you get additional vertical space (after the affiliation) from the unused `\institute` field. To get rid of it you'll need to redefine the title matter (as suggested in tikzposter documentation): `\settitle{ \centering \vbox{
\@titlegraphic \\[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] \centering
\color{titlefgcolor} {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
\vspace*{1em}
{\huge \@author \par}
}}`